# Group Control Multiple Chromium/Chrome Instance

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, automation, chromium, ui-automation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kI9SIcKMkIY&t=36s 
https://youtu.be/mVC77lREwhc?t=35

Above videos this is something new i have seen trending on antidetect browser automation, one master window controlling/syncing all chrome instance. so far i tested it works if window active over screen, if minimized not working, so it's something that calculate cordinate.

In the meantime i searched for it over youtube something shared related to autohotkey,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qviCMzDYMRA but not sure how it's done.

Anyone have idea, how it's implemented, and possible to do with other automations?
i am very curious to know the concept of it, how it's possible actually with selenium multiple etc.